# Is it legal to place the return keyword not on the end of the function but having it in the middle?

Tags: php, return

I have a function like this:

```
function database_connect(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli($_POST['mysql_host'],$_POST['mysql_username'],$_POST['mysql_password']);
    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    /* check if server is alive */
    if ($mysqli->ping()) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Is it legal to place the return keyword not on the end of the function but having it in the middle?

And is it legal to use return more then once in one function?

Comment: `$mysqli->close();` is useless anyway.

Comment: Yes, for both questions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is syntactically acceptable to use `return` anywhere in the function, as is using multiple return statements. Remember that no further code will be executed after you return, so your `$mysqli->close()` won't execute.

For readability though, you might prefer to have a single exit point for the function.

Consider this alternative that uses a single exit point:

```
function database_connect(){
    $output = false;

    $mysqli = new mysqli($_POST['mysql_host'],$_POST['mysql_username'],$_POST['mysql_password']);

    /* check connection */
    if (!$mysqli->connect_errno) {

        /* check if server is alive */
        if ($mysqli->ping()) {
            $output = true;
        }

    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can absolutely have `return` anywhere in your function. You can also have multiple returns inside a function, based on different conditions.

Just be aware that any code below it will not execute, once *any* return has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you can put `return` where you want that function return and not proceed the execution.

`For Example:`

In you code the function `database_connect()` is `returning` the from `if condition` if the `credentials are not valid` otherwise the execution will `proceed if they valid`

That is legal and valid by `syntactically` and even `logically`.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

it is legal in the sense that **cyber police** won't arrest you.

But If you look closely, you have an *if/else* statement, where both *if* and *else* contains a `return`. In this case the remaining code is ignored. In conclusion, the last instruction `$mysqli->close();` is never executed because `PHP` exits from the function when you call your `return`.

I'd use something like:

```
function database_connect(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli($_POST['mysql_host'],$_POST['mysql_username'],$_POST['mysql_password']);
    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return_state=FALSE;        
    /* check if server is alive */
    if ($mysqli->ping()) {
        return TRUE;

    $mysqli->close();
    return return_state;


}
```